# Trying to setup Ceph

Tags: command-line, 16.04, nautilus, ceph

I am trying to set up Ceph on my Ubuntu server for my Dissertation work.

I'm trying to set things up so that the Ceph user can access all the Ceph nodes without needing a password, however my original user doesn't seem to have authorization to run this change...
the first line works

```
$ echo "ceph-system ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/ceph-system
```

the second line seems to indicate that I don't have access to the sudoers file.

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/ceph-system
```

Comment: Changing permissions of files that you don't own usually requires the use of `sudo`.

Comment: It turns out the first user you create when you install the OS is not a root user, and I had to use the ``sudo -s`` to enter root. I have promoted the user to a super user now though

Comment: The first user you create in Ubuntu is *automatically* an admin user (already in the 'sudo' group). You can simply prepend commands with sudo instead of changing users.